# Receiving permission denied when using 'sudo -u' in a script when OpenVPN is started as a service

Tags: shell-script, sudo, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN `--route-up` script that does something and then executes another script that starts qbittorrent in background using `sudo -u`. The script works fine when starting OpenVPN via `sudo openvpn --config path/to/conf/file`, but when `/etc/default/openvpn` is configured, and the machine is restarted or OpenVPN is started using `sudo service openvpn start` the script errors out because root supposedly doesn't have the required permissions. The following errors are printed out in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
sudo: unable to change directory to /home/vbox: Permission denied
sudo: unable to execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
```

The main `--route-up` script starts the other script after it finishes like this:

```
sudo -i -u vbox /etc/openvpn/start-qbit &
```

`/etc/openvpn/start-qbit`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Has to be started as user (vbox) via `sudo -i -u vbox`

echo "Starting qbittorrent"

# The env variables set the correct display and enable user's themes
export DISPLAY=:0
export KDE_FULL_SESSION=true

setsid qbittorrent &>/dev/null
```

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 in a VirtualBox

Comment: Does the directory /home/vbox exist? Can post "/bin/ls -ldt /home/vbox"?

Comment: Oh wow, thats weird. It seems like the directory doesn't exist in this case. `/bin/ls: cannot access '/home/vbox': No such file or directory`. Would you know what causes this issue? This only happens when OpenVPN is ran as a service.